# Test oauth2 get_token with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, oauth-2.0, webmock

I'm creating a controller spec for the get_token part of an oauth2 authentication. At this point the user has authorized my app and I need to generate and save the token and other information. Rspec fails with a somewhat cryptic error.

```
Failure/Error: get :auth, { code: "auth_code", scope: "read_write" }
     OAuth2::Error:
       {:token_type=>"bearer", 
        :stripe_publishable_key=>"PUBLISHABLE_KEY", 
        :scope=>"read_write", 
        :livemode=>"false", 
        :stripe_user_id=>"USER_ID",  
        :refresh_token=>"REFRESH_TOKEN", 
        :access_token=>"ACCESS_TOKEN"}
```

Here's the controller code. Rspec says it fails on get_token.

```
require 'oauth2'

def auth
  code = params[:code]
  client = oauth_client
  token_response = client.auth_code.get_token(code, params: { scope: 'read_write' })
  token = token_response.token
```

And here's the test. The webmock should be intercepting get_token. It is the autogenerated webmock suggeted by rspec that I filled in the body with the appropriate request and response body.

```
before do
  stub_request(:post, "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token").
    with(:body => {"client_id"=>"CLIENT_ID",
                   "client_secret"=>"SOME_SECRET",
                   "code"=>"auth_code",
                   "grant_type"=>"authorization_code",
                   "params"=>{"scope"=>"read_write"}},
         :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*',
                      'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
                      'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.9.0'}).
    to_return(:status => 200,
              :body => {token_type: "bearer",
                        stripe_publishable_key: "PUBLISHABLE_KEY",
                        scope: "read_write",
                        livemode: "false",
                        stripe_user_id: "USER_ID",
                        refresh_token: "REFRESH_TOKEN",
                        access_token: "ACCESS_TOKEN"},
              :headers => {})
end

describe "#auth" do
  it "creates a payment gateway" do
    get :auth, { code: "auth_code", scope: "read_write" 
  end
end
```

This process already works in practice so at least the controller code is not to blame. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

After work hard having the same problem I have a solution. Is the **header** returned in the stub request, you have it blank. The oauth2 gem use the Content-Type to define how to parse the body. Try the stub putting the header in this way:

```
stub_request(:post, "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token").
    with(:body => {"client_id"=>"CLIENT_ID",
                   "client_secret"=>"SOME_SECRET",
                   "code"=>"auth_code",
                   "grant_type"=>"authorization_code",
                   "params"=>{"scope"=>"read_write"}},
         :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*',
                      'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
                      'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.9.0'}).
    to_return(:status => 200,
              :body => {token_type: "bearer",
                        stripe_publishable_key: "PUBLISHABLE_KEY",
                        scope: "read_write",
                        livemode: "false",
                        stripe_user_id: "USER_ID",
                        refresh_token: "REFRESH_TOKEN",
                        access_token: "ACCESS_TOKEN"},
              :headers => { 'Content-Type'=> 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting this error, because you've stubbed only part of oauth session, i.e. you're trying to send a stale token (or something like that) that has been provided by webmock.

Instead of manual stubbing of these requests, I'd suggest to use special tool: [stripe-ruby-mock gem](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock), which has been designed exactly for testing Stripe API.

As an alternative, you may use [`VCR` gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) (here are [the docs](http://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs)), which allows to write on disk all your http session and play it as it was live. Great tool, highly recommended.